# Panning and zooming more than one map at once while interacting with only one map

Tags: maps, openlayers, zooming, interaction, panning

I have two Openlayers maps displaying two images (png files) of an area of sky at two different (radio) frequencies.

I would like to know if it'd possible to replicate the result of a panning or zooming on one map to the other map and reciprocally. In other words I'd like to have the effect of one interaction (Pan - Zoom ) with one window simultaneoulsy replicated on the other map.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by listening to the events of one [ol.View](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html) and apply them on the second map.

With `change:resolution` you can catch zooming and with `change:center` the panning.

```js
var view = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0], zoom: 2
});
var view2 = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0], zoom: 2
});
var source = new ol.source.OSM();

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: source
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});
var map2 = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map2',
  view: view2
});

function updateView(event, viewRef){
  let newValue = event.target.get(event.key);

  if(event.key === 'center') {
    // we need to transform the value, it comes in an other projection
    newValue = ol.proj.transform(newValue , source.getProjection(), 'EPSG:3857');
    // offset the value somehow here
  }
  viewRef.set(event.key, newValue);
}

view.on('change:resolution', function(event){
  updateView(event, view2);
});

view.on('change:center', function(event){
  updateView(event, view2);
});
```

```css
.map{
    max-height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="map2" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Dear dube. Thank you so much. It works at the perfection for my use case. Actually I did not need the statement :      newValue = ol.proj.transform(newValue , source.getProjection(), 'EPSG:3857');

Comment: Nice! _I think_ that depends on the type of your basemap